# Refresh Datagrid after adding a new Customer MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

This my view Main:

[image]

XAML View Main :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedrole}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RoleList}">
  <Button Content="Add Role"
          Command="{Binding  AddRole}"
          Height="35"/>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel Main:

```
public RoleManagementViewModel()
{
    roleList = new ObservableCollection<UserRoleClass>(WCFclient.GetAllRoles());
    _addRole = new RelayCommand<string>(AddRoleFunction);           
}    

private void AddRoleFunction(object obj)
{
    if (!Application.Current.Windows.OfType<SelectionCompartementView>().Any())
    {              
        AddRoleView winAddRole = new AddRoleView();
        winAddRole.DataContext = new AddRoleViewModel();
        winAddRole.Show();
        winAddRole.Topmost = true;
        winAddRole.Focus();
    }           
}

public ObservableCollection<UserRoleClass> RoleList
{
    get { return roleList; }
    set
    {
        roleList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RoleList");
    }
}
```

The view Add Role:
[image]

Xaml Add-Role:

```
<Button x:Name="button1"
        Command="{Binding SaveRole}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddRole}"/>
```

ViewModel Add-Role:

```
public AddRoleViewModel()
{
    _addOrUpdate = new UserRoleClass();
    _addOrUpdate = new UserRoleClass();
    saveRole = new RelayCommand<Window>(addFunc);
}

private void addFunc(Window window)
{
    UserRoleClass newRole = new UserRoleClass()
    {
        name = AddOrUpdate.name,
        description = AddOrUpdate.description,
    };                                             
    int resultSave = WCFclient.saveRole(newRole);          
    if (resultSave == 0)
    {
        String UpdateInformation0 = "Role is saved successfully";
        string sCaption = "Save Role";
        MessageBoxButton btnMessageBox = MessageBoxButton.OK;
        MessageBoxImage icnMessageBox = MessageBoxImage.Information;
        MessageBoxResult rsltMessageBox = MessageBox.Show(
            UpdateInformation0, sCaption, btnMessageBox, icnMessageBox);
    }
    if (window != null)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
}    

private ICommand saveRole;
public ICommand SaveRole
{
    get { return saveRole; }
}
```

It works fine: when I add a new `Role`, the view of Add-Role closes and returns to the view Main, and I have a result in database... but not in the `DataGrid` in MainView.

How can I refresh directly?

Comment: You should learn MVVM. This is all much harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why do you have two of the following line? 
`_addOrUpdate = new UserRoleClass();`

Second, when you save your new role, it seems you're calling a WCF service that saves it to the DB.
You're using an observable collection which should update when you add to it, but I don't see your code adding the new role into the `RoleList`.

Comment: @devtunis No prob. Glad it helped. For future references, remember this question, and ask yourself: `what am I saving, and what am I'm expecting to happen` :). (I've probably done the same more than once)

Comment: I see that :)
Thank you a lot for this advice
I will do this astuce from now

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do it is with something like this.

```
 public AddRoleViewModel(Action<UserRoleClass> onAdded = null)
    {
        _addOrUpdate = new UserRoleClass();          
        _addOrUpdate = new UserRoleClass();
        _onAdded = onAdded;
        saveRole = new RelayCommand<Window>(addFunc);           
    }

    private void addFunc(Window window)
    {
        UserRoleClass newRole = new UserRoleClass()
        {
            name = AddOrUpdate.name,
            description = AddOrUpdate.description,
        };                                             
             int resultSave = WCFclient.saveRole(newRole);          
            if (resultSave == 0)
             {
                 String UpdateInformation0 = "Role is saved successfully";
                 string sCaption = "Save Role";
                 MessageBoxButton btnMessageBox = MessageBoxButton.OK;
                 MessageBoxImage icnMessageBox = MessageBoxImage.Information;
                 MessageBoxResult rsltMessageBox = MessageBox.Show(UpdateInformation0, sCaption, btnMessageBox, icnMessageBox);
             }           

         }
         _onAdded?.Invoke(newRole);           
         if (window != null)
         {

             window.Close();
         }
```

And when you create the ViewModel

```
 new AddRoleViewModel(newItem=>{ RoleList.Add(newItem); });
```

But I can't say I like the architecture all that much. If might want to look at some sort of a [messenger service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with binding datagrid to an observable collection. The binding updates if the collection changes not if the collection content changes. The best way to do this, after adding the new UserRole to the RoleList is to use a "deep" observable collection like this one:

```
public sealed class DeepObservableCollection<T>
    : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemPropertyChanged;

    public DeepObservableCollection() {
        CollectionChanged += DeepObservableCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public DeepObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        : base(collection) {
        CollectionChanged += DeepObservableCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public DeepObservableCollection( List<T> collection )
        : base( collection ) {
        CollectionChanged += DeepObservableCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void DeepObservableCollection_CollectionChanged( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
        if ( e.NewItems != null ) {
            foreach ( var item in e.NewItems ) {
                var notifyPropertyChanged = item as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if ( notifyPropertyChanged != null ) notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if ( e.OldItems != null ) {
            foreach ( Object item in e.OldItems ) {
                var notifyPropertyChanged = item as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if ( notifyPropertyChanged != null ) notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    void item_PropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs( NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset );
        OnCollectionChanged( a );

        ItemPropertyChanged?.Invoke( sender, e );
    }
}
```

your UserRoleClass must implement INotifyPropertyChanged (maybe using ObservableObject) but that's all what is required. When you add a new user role datagrid updates through binding.